# Alexa to ask me something as part of a routine

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, smartthings

I'm looking for a way that Alexa responds with a question after I give her a command. My case:

My setup is an Alexa with Samsung SmartThings with a ton of devices. When I tell Alexa --> Good morning, she disables my alarm and tells me the weather forecast. Now, I also want her to ask me back, if I would like a coffee. (I have a Wemos D1 in my Jura Z5 and a custom device handler in SmartThings). I don't always want a coffee, that's why I don't want to add it to my standard good morning routine. So it would be really cool if she could ask: "Would you like a coffee?" and I just have to reply "yes" or "no" and she does her thing.

Comment: So what problem are you having getting it to do that?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Honestly I don't even know where to start. Any search I've done brought no results. Maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing. Search results are only stupid things you can ask alexa. I don't see an option in the alexa app. I'm no programmer by any means. I can mod code, copy & paste and follow instructions, but I'm far from writing my own code. I was thinking of installing echosistant or AskAlexa, but I don't even know if that has any option to have alexa follow up with a question... Really, any help would be much appreciated. Has this been done before? Or maybe something similar? Thanks, Andre

Comment: It's not possible, so maybe just move 'the if' outside the routines and create other one with coffee making step (you can copy all steps to new routine in the Alexa app) :) and then tell Alexa "Good morning" or "Coffee and good morning" - just you need to decide if you want a coffee before you start the routine ;)